# How to avoid circular dependency among widgets in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

My `Bluetooth` app has a few buttons to play with `Bluetooth` settings. Whenever I tried to change position / move a widget in the `activity_bluetooth.xml` file, another widget on the layout get dragged along or overlap each other as if they were interconnected. I am only selecting one widget at a time. How can I stop this inter-widget dependency?

**Rendering problems: Exception raised during rendering**

[image: Layout rendering error]

Comment: You can edit the xml directly.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of `RelativeLayout` so  can layout children relative to each other and to the root view. By using `layout:alignComponent` (in the visual design editor) you can let Android know to make the position of the current view relative to other view in your layout.

The reason other views move when you move the button is because the other views have specified their positioning relative to the button that you're now moving (via `layout:alignComponent`) so their positioning is moving along with that button. So to get rid of this dependency on your button just go through each view, look for a `layout:alignComponent` referencing your button and delete it. The reason that AS is giving you a Circular Dependency exception is usually because not only are other views using `layout:alignComponent` to position themselves relative to your button but also because your button is referencing one or more of the other views in the its own `layout:alignComponent`.

For example; if button1s left edge is set to be relative to button2s left edge and button2s left edge is set to be relative to button1s left edge then that creates a problem. If they both depend on each other for their layout positioning then how does Android know which one to layout first?